# Using $.post with CodeIgniter URL issue

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have one page in CodeIgniter with URL `http://127.0.0.1/FOLDER/data/getList`.

On that page, there is list of enteries. On that list, in every item there is a link on which by clicking I need to fetch some data using `$.post` jQuery.

I have used this code:

```
$(".class_name").click(function() {
    $val = $(this).attr('val')
    $.post("class/func", {val:$val}, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

The issue is with the URL to be used with `$.post`.

If I use, `"/class/func"`, it sends the requsts to `http://127.0.0.1/class/func` **(FOLDER is not getting in)**.

If I use, `"class/func"`, it sends the request to 
`http://127.0.0.1/FOLDER/data/class/func` **(here data gets inserted which is class for the current page)**.

How should I resolve this error? Should I be using `<?php echo base_url() ?>class/func`; is it the correct way of doing it?

Comment: `/class/func` this is called root relative, that is `/` slash used before class denotes the root. So it makes a url just like `http://localhost/class/func`.

Answer (score 1):

### If your JavaScript code is between `<script></script>` in your view:

```
$.post("<?php echo site_url("class/func") ?>", {val:$val}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

---

### If your JavaScript is on a separate .js file:

In the footer of your page:

```
<script>var baseUrl = "<?php echo base_url() ?>";</script>
```

And then:

```
$.post(baseUrl + "index.php/class/func", {val:$val}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

**Alternative :**

Set a data-attribute to your item

```
<a href="#nogo" data-ajaxurl="<?php echo site_url("controller/funct") ?>" class="classname">Go!</a>
```

And then:

```
$.post($(this).data("ajaxurl"), {val:$val}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a separate js file from where I had to call the function in a controller "Verifypass.php". I had something like this in the $_post():

```
$.post( "verifypass", { pass: $("#password").val() }, function(data){


});
```

This did not work for me, So all I did was to add index.php at the beginning of the controller name as:

```
$.post( "index.php/verifypass", { pass: $("#password").val() }, function(data){



});
```

And it worked then.